# Self generate Woocommerce Variable Products download links

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a Woocommerece shop in Wordpress with Themify and running this as a photo libary. The goal is that anyone with access can select the right file-sized images for there job.

I'm using variable products to "sell" downloadable content in 3 sizes, Digital/Print and Professional Print. My aim if possible is that when you upload a high-res image(professional print) the print/digital print sections are automatically filled by sourcing the large/medium file types generated by Wordpress on upload.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to tackle this? I'm a little out of my depth on this one.

Comment: are you insert images individually for variations ?

Comment: The highest quality image will be manually inserted, then i'd like to automate the other 2 from the default sizes generated from wordpress.